# Can sick villagers die?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Whenever I play ACNL, I find my villagers are sick, but if they get too sick, can they die? I have tried testing this on an undesirable but  forgot to play and when I came back they were gone from my town. Although, before they got sick they had been planning to leave so I think they may have just left.

Comment: I never saw someone die in Animal Crossing. I can't say that I'm 100% sure about that, but most of the time, you can help heal them just for the sake of deepening your friendship with them and win some presents.
If they are sick and you don't give them anything, they will just be sick for a couple of days and then be healthy again.
It would be weird for them to die in Animal Crossing ^^

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if they could die or not. I was guessing that they would move out to another town where someone would help them if they couldn't die.

Answer (score 3):

## No

The sickness will last from one to fourteen days, or until you give them medicine.

Your villagers will never die.

Source:
http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Sickness

Answer (score 0):

No, in this game no characters die. A good indication of this is by the PEGI rating (or ESRB rating) that the game has, PEGI 3 (or E from the ESRB). This indicates the game is suitable for children up to 3 years of age. Death is not an easy term to explain to children at this age.

Answer (score -3):

It is impossible for a villager to "die".

- In Wild World, your charater can die and will just look like a gyroid and have devil like horns.
- In New leaf - they can't.
- In City Folk - they might even lose their keys and you must dig them up!